A function in the p-adics that vanishes infinitely many times.
I know that the quantity
$$
Q_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n c_k \frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!}p^k
$$
where $c_k$ is an integer, vanishes for an infinite number of $n$.
This leads us to define $P_k(X) = c_k\frac{X(X-1)...(X-k+1)}{k!}$.
Next, we consider the formal series:
$$
P(X) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} p^k P_k(X)
$$
For every $n$ such that $Q_n$ vanishes, it is clear that $P(n) = 0$, so $P$ has an infinite number of "roots".
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then I showed that
$$
|p^k P_k(n)|_p = \frac{1}{p^k} |P_k(n)|_p \leq \frac{1}{p^k}
$$
since $P_k(n)$ is an integer for all $n$.
The general term of the series converges to 0 for all $n$, so $P(n)$ is well-defined for all $n$ in $p$-adic numbers.
$$
P(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} p^k P_k(n)
$$
How can you show that $P = 0$?
I don't know Strassman theorem, I am completely new to the field of p-adic numbers.

Just to clarify: There's a fixed sequence of integers $c_k$ given at the start of the whole argument, yes?

Also, if you give a bit more context (Where does the problem come from? What made you bring up that you don't know Strassman's Theorem, is it supposed to be used?), that would improve the question.

Yes, the ck are fixed in advance, and we know that they are integers. Their explicit form doesn't matter. I'm trying to prove the Skolem-Mahler theorem and have proved all the previous results I've mentioned. Then we are told to conclude that P = 0.

I saw in the literature that they use Strassmann's theorem, but I am not familiar with it, and the topic is intended to introduce p-adic numbers rather than delve into that theorem.

For positive $c_k$, I don't see how $Q_n$ could be $0$ at all, much less for infinitely many $n$. $Q_n$ is the sum of rational numbers, and $\Bbb Q$ is a subfield of the $p$-adics, just as it is of the reals. If $Q_n$ is $0$ for some $n$, it is $0$ in $\Bbb Q$, and as a sum of positive rationals, it cannot be $0$.

$c_k$ is not considered as positive

If you want more precision : I take $\langle (I + pB)^n A^r X, Y \rangle$  which is 0 for an infinite number of $n$ and all matrixes are with integer coefficients. If I develop the dot product I get $\sum_k {n \choose k}p^k \langle B^k A^r X, Y \rangle$

I don't see a good reason to not use Strassmann's theorem here. It's probably harder to find some super clever proof to avoid using it than it is to just prove that theorem itself.
